# SQL Query to find customers who registered and purchased on the same day

Tags: sql

I would like to get all the customers who registered and purchased on the same day given a startdate and enddate.

Below is the schema :

Users

```
--CustId
--PostedDate
```

Order

```
--OrderId
--CustId
--PostedDate
```

How do i write a query to pull same day registered and purchased orders within a specific date period?

Comment: These aren't full schemas. Are PostedDate date or datetime fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Users.CustId
FROM
    Users JOIN Order ON Users.CustId = Order.CustId
WHERE
    DATE(Users.PostedDate) = DATE(Order.PostedDate)
    AND Users.PostedDate BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date`
```

This is assuming `PostedDate` is a datetime and not date field. If it is in fact a date field, `DATE(Users.PostedDate) = DATE(Order.PostedDate)` can be shortened to `Users.PostedDate = Order.PostedDate`, and then that part of the WHERE clause can be a candidate for index usage.

Comment: Thanks richard.I feel bad for not taking some more time to figure out the solution myself before posting the question on stack overflow. Need a break.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT u.CustId FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN Orders AS o
ON u.CustId = o.CustId AND u.Posted Date = o.PostedDate
WHERE u.PostedDate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users, Order 
WHERE Users.CustId = Order.CustId AND 
      Users.PostedDate = Order.PostedDate
```

Comment: That works.But say i need to find customers who registered and purchased on the same date between 9/1/2011 to 10/1/2011. How do I do that?

Comment: @Sam: this will find orders which were added the same day user was registered

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u1.CustId  FROM Users u1, Order o1  WHERE u1.CustId = o1.CustId AND
  u1.PostedDate = o1.PostedDate and  o1.PostedDate between
  to_date('<startdate>','<oracleformat>') and to_date('fromdate','<>')+1
```