# SQL Query to find customers who registered and purchased on the 2nd day to within 7th day of their registration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get all the customers who registered and purchased on the 2nd day to  within 7th day of their registration given a startdate and enddate.

Below is the schema :

Users

```
--CustId
--PostedDate
```

Order

```
--OrderId
--CustId
--PostedDate
```

How do i write a query to pull same day registered and purchased orders on the 2nd day to  within 7th day of their registration within a specific date period?

Comment: This is a near duplicate of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628950/sql-query-to-find-customers-who-registered-and-purchased-on-the-same-day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very slightly modifying Richard Simoes's code from your other question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Users.CustId
FROM
    Users JOIN Order ON Users.CustId = Order.CustId
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(dd, Users.PostedDate, Order.PostedDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
    AND Users.PostedDate BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
```